# Sort Sales Data by Customer Name and Year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set which contains Customer Name, Ship Date, and PO Amount.

I would like to sort the data frame to output a table with the format of

```
cols:[Customer Name,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021]
rows: 1 row for each customer and the sum of PO's within a given year.
```

This is what I have tried:
The data is coming in from an excel sheet, but assume ShipToName is a String, Bill Amount is a Float, and Sell data is a datetime.datetime.year().

```
ShipToName = ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Josh', 'Bob','Joe','Josh']
BillAmount = [30.02,23.2,20,45.32,54.23,65]
SellDate = [2016,2016,2018,2020,2021,2018]

dfSales = {'Customer': ShipToName, 'Total Sales': BillAmmount, 
'Year':SellDate}
dfSales = pd.DataFrame(dfSales,columns = ['Customer', 'Year','Total 
Sales'])
dfbyyear = dfSales.groupby(['Customer','Year'], as_index = 
False).sum().sort_values('Total Sales', ascending = False)
```

This gives me a new row for each customer/year combo.

I would like the output to look like:

| Customer Name | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 30.02 |  |  |  | 45.32 |  |
| Joe | 23.20 |  |  |  |  | 54.23 |
| Josh |  |  | 85.00 |  |  |  |

Comment: Can you share input data and also share what your expected output will be please?

Comment: I have edited the comment. Sorry, first post.

Comment: Looks like you need a pivot table of the final results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit v2

Using the data from the original version, we can create a temp dataframe `dx` that groups the data by Customer Name and Year. Then we can pivot the data to the format you wanted.

```
dx = df.groupby(['Customer Name','Year'])['PO Amount'].agg(Total_Amt=sum).reset_index()

dp = dx.pivot(index='Customer Name',columns='Year',values='Total_Amt')

print (dp)
```

The output of this will be:

```
Year           2020  2021
Customer Name            
Boby           6754  6371
Jack           5887  6421
Jane           5161  4411
Jill           5857  5641
Kate           6205  6457
Suzy           5027  4561
```

## Original v1

I am making some assumptions with the data as you haven't provided me with any.

Assumptions:

1. There are many customers in the dataframe - My example has 6
   customers
2. Each customer has more than one Ship Date - My example has 1
   shipment each month for 2 years
3. The shipment amount is a dollar amount - I used integer range from 100 to 900
4. The total dataframe size is 144 rows with 3 columns - Customer Name, Ship Date, and PO Amount
5. You are looking for an output by Customer, by Year, sum of all POs for that year

With these assumptions, here's the dataframe and the output.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer Name':['Jack'] * 24 + ['Jill'] * 24 + ['Jane'] * 24 + 
                                   ['Kate'] * 24 + ['Suzy'] * 24 + ['Boby'] * 24,
                   'Ship Date':pd.date_range('2020-01-01',periods = 24,freq='MS').tolist()*6,
                   'PO Amount':[random.randint(100,900) for _ in range(144)]})
print (df)
df['Year'] = df['Ship Date'].dt.year

print (df.groupby(['Customer Name','Year'])['PO Amount'].agg(Total_Amt=sum).reset_index())

    Customer Name  Ship Date  PO Amount
0            Jack 2020-01-01        310
1            Jack 2020-02-01        677
2            Jack 2020-03-01        355
3            Jack 2020-04-01        571
4            Jack 2020-05-01        875
..            ...        ...        ...
139          Boby 2021-08-01        116
140          Boby 2021-09-01        822
141          Boby 2021-10-01        751
142          Boby 2021-11-01        109
143          Boby 2021-12-01        866
```

Each customer has data from `2020-01-01` through `2021-12-01`.

The summary report will be as follows:

```
   Customer Name  Year  Total_Amt
0           Boby  2020       7176
1           Boby  2021       6049
2           Jack  2020       6187
3           Jack  2021       5240
4           Jane  2020       4919
5           Jane  2021       6105
6           Jill  2020       6556
7           Jill  2021       5963
8           Kate  2020       6300
9           Kate  2021       6360
10          Suzy  2020       5969
11          Suzy  2021       4866
```

Comment: I have edited the post to include a table of "what I'm looking for". Sorry, first post. Still trying to find my way around. 

Currently I am getting what you are reporting. I would like a single row for each name and multiple columns for the years in the data set.

Comment: @JoshRandles,  See if the updated answer helps you get the results in the format you asked for.

Comment: The updated answer was exactly what I was asking for. Additionally, is there a way to format the years columns to be in Currency format. Ex. Instead of 6754 it is $6,754.00. I can do this in the data frame using the map format but it will not allow me to do this to the pivot table.

Comment: I was able to have the pivot table show dollars by shifting the pd display options:
pd.options.display.float_format='${:,.2f}'.format